# First order differential equation with a derivative delta function

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dirac-delta

I have to solve the first order differential equation:

$$ f'(x) - \text{i}\,k\,f(x)=\text{i}\,a\, f'(x)\,\delta(x)$$

where $k$ and $a$ are reals and "i" is the complex number: $\text{i}^2=-1$. $\delta(x)$ is the delta function (Dirac function).

We have the solution for $x\neq 0$:

$$f(x)=A\,e^{\text{i}kx}\quad\text{for}\, x>0$$

and

$$f(x)=B\,e^{\text{i}kx}\quad \text{for}\, x<0$$

The solution can be written as

$$f(x)=\text{e}^{\text{i}kx}\, \Big(A\,\Theta(x)+ B\,\Theta(-x)\Big)$$

I need to find a relation between A and B. We can integrate the differential equation around $x=0$ but $f(x)$ and $f'(x)$ are not necessary continious at $x=0$. I saw an *average* equation:

$$\int_{-\epsilon}^\epsilon f'(x)\,\delta(x)=\dfrac{f'(0^+)+f'(0^-)}{2}$$

Is it always true or we have to take some precautions?

Answer (score 1):

Approximating $δ(x)$ by the rectangular function $\frac1ε \chi_{[s,s+ε]}(x)$ gives an ODE 
\begin{cases}
\qquad f'(x)-ikf(x)=0&\text{ for }x<s\text{ or }x>s+ε\\
(1-ia/ε)f'(x)-ikf(x)=0&\text{ for }s\le x\le s+ε
\end{cases}
that has a continuous solution
$$
f(x)=\begin{cases}
c_0e^{ikx}&x<s\\
c_1e^{-kx\frac{ε}{a+iε}}& s\le x\le s+ε\\
c_2e^{ikx}&s+ε<x
\end{cases}
$$
if for continuity at $s$ and $s+ε$ the constants are connected as
$$
c_0=c_1e^{-ks\frac{ia}{a+iε}} \text{ and }c_2=c_1e^{-k(s+ε)\frac{ia}{a+iε}}
$$
which in the limit $(s,ε)\to(0,0)$ leads to the function $f(x)=c_0e^{ikx}$ which obviously is not a solution at $x=0$. Thus the equation is not solvable.